# Bootstrap Align Center Collapsed Items for Navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a problem of converting the alignment of navbar from desktop to mobile. I want the items in the navbar to be aligned center when collapsed without affecting the alignment in desktop view. This is the website: http://www.heights-ateneo.org

CSS:

```
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #320143;
  color: #999999;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #320143;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="background-color: #320143; margin-bottom:0px;">
  <div class="container-fluid" id = "navbarcontainer" style = "margin-right:12%;">
    <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse" style="border-color: #320143;"> 
        <span class= "icon-bar"></span>
        <span class= "icon-bar"></span>
        <span class= "icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" style="height:100vh;">
        <div class = "col-sm-5" style = "text-align: left;">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li  style="top: 9px;">
                <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn"  id="collapsed"><font face = "Tinos" size = "4"><b>Articles</b></font><span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="http://www.heights-ateneo.org/news.php"  id="collapsed"><font face = "Tinos" size = "4"><b>News</b></font></a>
                    <a href="http://www.heights-ateneo.org/features.php"  id="collapsed"><font face = "Tinos" size = "4"><b>Features</b></font></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </li><li style="top: 12px;"><a href="http://www.heights-ateneo.org/folios.php" ><font face = "Tinos" size = "4"><b>Folios</b></font></a></li>
                <li style="top: 12px;"><a href="http://www.heights-ateneo.org/CFC.php" ><font face = "Tinos" size = "4"><b>Contribute</b></font></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-sm-1" style = "text-align: center;">
            <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"  id="collapsed"> <div class="navbar-brand button-icon hlogo"></div></a>
            <div><span></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-sm-6" style = "text-align: left;">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style = "margin-right: -20px;">
                <li style ="top:9px;">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn" id = "abtbtn"><font face = "Tinos" size = "4"><b>About</b></font><span class="caret"></span></button>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="http://www.heights-ateneo.org/about.php/"  id="collapsed"><font face = "Tinos" size = "4"><b>About Us</b></font></a>
                        <a href="http://www.heights-ateneo.org/about.php/#history"  id="collapsed"><font face = "Tinos" size = "4"><b>History</b></font></a>
                        <a href="http://www.heights-ateneo.org/about.php/#projects"  id="collapsed"><font face = "Tinos" size = "4"><b>Projects</b></font></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li style="top: 12px;"><a href="http://www.heights-ateneo.org/contact.php" ><font face = "Tinos" size = "4"><b>Contact</b></font></a></li>
                <li style="top: 22px; margin-left:12px; margin-right:20px;"><div class="search-box"><div class="search-container">
                    <!-- <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span> -->
                    <form action="http://heights-ateneo.org/" method="get" class="form-inline"><font face = "Tinos" size = "3"><input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search..." name="s"/></font>
                </div></div></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>      
   </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Adding an align-center in the css will affect it in the desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try media queries (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).

It lets you style the mobile versions however you want, without it affecting desktop size.